Networkx: convert a MultiDiGraph to a DiGraph while summing up the weights of multiple edges between the same pair of nodes
I have a MultiDiGraph that is created in a "clean" way, but then goes over several graph transformations (node merges) which may result in multiple edges between the same pair of nodes u and v (in the same direction u -> v), all having weights that may even have the same value. I want to transform the MultiDiGraph into a DiGraph such that the single resulting edge between u -> v has a weight equal to the sum of weights of the original u -> v edges in the MultiDiGraph. I understand the default behavior is to keep only the latest edge added between u and v. Is there any option where the conversion actually calculates the weight-sum and uses that as the final weight? (seems to me that this would actually be the most desired behavior). Is "manually" traversing nodes and edges of the MultiDiGraph to create the DiGraph the only way to achieve this?
The simplified code below illustrates the point. I'd like "edge_weight" to be 14, even though it's 5 as it stands.
import networkx as nx

G = nx.MultiDiGraph()

# Add 4 edges u->v with individual weights
G.add_edge('u', 'v', weight=7)
G.add_edge('u', 'v', weight=1)  # weight is 1 for this edge
G.add_edge('u', 'v', weight=1)  # weight is also 1 for this other edge
G.add_edge('u', 'v', weight=5)

H = nx.DiGraph(G)

edge_weight = H['u']['v']['weight']

print(edge_weight)

I understand this question has been answered in here:
Combining edges by summing their (symbolic) weights
however the answer there does not explicitly state whether there is actually a function within networkx that performs such conversion between a MultiDiGraph to a DiGraph or not, namely, the only solution is indeed the "manual" approach stated there. It would be nice to edit that solution by stating that networkx does not indeed have any such solution.
